# How to write an NSPredicate to search date attribute of to-many relationship?

Tags: swift, core-data, predicate

I have a "Patient" object with a to-many relationship to an "Act" object (Patient.acts)
An Act object has a startDate attribute of type Date

I am trying to write the NSPredicate to get all patients who have at least one act whose startDate is today

I am on XCode 10, using swift 4.2

I cannot figure out the correct left expression in:

```
let start = NSExpression(forConstantValue: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date()))
let end = NSExpression(forConstantValue: Calendar.current.endOfDay(for: Date()))
let todayRange = NSExpression(forAggregate: [start, end])
let actToday = NSComparisonPredicate(leftExpression: ????, rightExpression: todayRange, modifier: .any, type: .between, options: [])
```

for the leftExpression, I have tried several options but nothing works:

```
let left = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "acts.startDate")
```

I have tried a subpredicate approach:

```
let actDate = NSPredicate(format: "$x.startDate")
let left = NSExpression(forSubquery: NSExpression(forKeyPath: "acts"), usingIteratorVariable: "x", predicate: actDate2)
```

**UPDATE and answer**

I have come up with the following expression:

```
let seenToday = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(acts, $v, $v.actStartDate => %@ && $v.actStartDate < %@).@count!=0", argumentArray:[startToday, endToday] )
```

Thanks to vadian for his answer. The question I wonder now is, is it more efficient to do it the way vadian proposes or is my subquery predicate adequate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to fetch all **acts** for the given date and map them to their patient attribute (assuming there is an appropriate reverse relationship in `Act`)

```
let interval = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .day, for: Date())!
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Act> = Act.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "startDate BETWEEN %@", [interval.start, interval.end] as [CVarArg])
```

Then fetch the acts and map the result to a set of patients

```
let acts = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
let patients = Set(acts.map{$0.patient})
```